# What is the name of a type that is defined from a template?

Tags: c++, terminology

To give a complete example, let's say I have a template class that I now use to generate a type definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {};

using X = // I'm not asking about this
  A<int>; // I want to know what this is
```

What is the name of `A<int>`? My initial thoughts were that it was a *generic specialisation* of `A`, because I recall reading that somewhere in reference to the standard, but I can't find it now.

The answer should make reference to the standard or, if that is not possible, cite an authoritative source that sets some sort of precedent for how it is named.

I know these kinds of questions are borderline but I don't know of any other place to ask them and I've done my best to address the points raised in this [meta discussion about questions on naming](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias. In the standard the technical term would be "alias-declaration".

Comment: `A<int>` is an instantiated template (or sometimes a template instantiation)

Comment: I guess my question is more about what `A<int>` is in comparison to an actual _specialisation_, I should have made that clearer.

Comment: How is this question "primarily opinion-based?" Call it off-topic if you want because "name that thing" is not on-topic, but there is a well-defined answer to this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking "name that thing."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just an alias: it takes `A<T>` , instantiate it with `T=int` and calls it `X`

Declare `X a;` and `a` will be an `A<int>`.

The documentation is as [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

[Here are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287151/difference-between-typedef-and-c11-type-alias) some references.

About A it is a "template instantiation": the generic type A is compiled using `int` in the place of `T`.

It is like `vector<int>` respect to `vector<double>` starting from `vector<T>`

Comment: I think I didn't explain it very well, but I'm not interested in what the `using` statement is, but rather `A<int>`.

Comment: Great, thanks. So if I wanted to distinguish between a _specialised_ instantiation and a normal template instantiation, e.g. `std::vector<bool>` and `std::vector<double>` could I refer to the latter as a "generic specialisation"?

Comment: No. `vector<T>` is a "geberic type" because `T` is a formal parameter (and not an existing type). The declaration is `template<class T> class vector { ... };`.  `vector<int> a` is the declaration of the variable `a` of type `vector<int>`;  `vector<bool> b` is the declaration of the variable `b` of type `vector<bool>`;  The fact the actual code of vector<int> and vector<bool> is different depends on the fact there is  a `template<> class vector<bool>{...};` somewhere in the `<vector>` header, not on the fact the `vector<bool>` is used here or there to instantiate this or that variable.

Comment: Note that `vector<T> a;` is not the declaration of 'a' of type `vector<T>`: is just a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Meyers' Effective Modern C++ mentions "function templates (i.e., templates that generate functions) and template functions (i.e., the functions generated from function templates)."

`A` can be called a struct template, and `A<int>` can be called a template struct.